# What HTML element should I use for date and time values so that it can be compared with another date time value in PHP

Tags: php, html

I am working on a project (only for practice, as I am a newbie to web development), which is an online parking system. User can book parking spaces/slots for certain time on specified places.

At first I take inputs from user like selecting the parking lot out of many, vehicle number, and then in-time and out-time. These values are forwarded to another page and then I store them in session variables.

After confirmation I am gonna store these values in SQL database.

Now, the values which are stored in database can't be updated automatically.
So the values are checked by the webpage everytime a new session loads.

The first thing while page is loading is it is gonna call every booked value from the database, the corresponding out-time with the current_time[while loading of page]. And if tha out-time is passed, then it's gonna update the values of that row, free all the columns except tha `slot_id` and change the status to free.

The problem is, the format in which date and time are stored in html and php is different.

I can use input `type="datetime"` or **input** `type="date"` and `type="date"` as two different values, but in both the cases I don't know how to compare these values with another time values in php.

How can I get over this.

Please suggest any improvements in my logic if something is wrong.

Comment: you should have a look at PHP's `DateTime` class - http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways you can handle this:
1. You can use PHP's DateTime class to convert the HTML date into the format you want.
2. You can use `date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date))` if you want to have a full timestamp or `date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date))` if you just want the date.

Both these are comparable to MySQL format dates and even if somehow they aren't you can use the same methods on the data you fetch from the db and compare the dates.

Comment: Thanks!
I want both date and time. And how are two time values compared. Can it be compared the same way as two different integers are compared [using ">"/"<" operators ].

Comment: Yes these operators should work. I know for sure that it works for Datetime you just need to check the `date()` if you want

Comment: @SamarpitShrivastava please accept the answer if it works thank you :)

Comment: So then should I store date and time as two different entities? There isn't a way to store both date and time in a single value column.

Comment: No you see the `Datetime` and `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')` store the date and time in one entity as a timestamp.

Comment: If you want the date alone you set it by specifying the format as `Y-m-d` instead of `Y-m-d H:i:s`. You can choose any format you want as well but for MySQL timestamp you use `Y-m-d H:i:s`. I hope i didn't confuse you.